# Only saving the last entry

Tags: php, database, dynamic

I have a form to edit the entrys in the database. With this the staff from my site can change every entry of an movie. It works percetly expect one little thing: It's also possible to change every episode title by iteselfs, and because every movie can have other count of episode, the php has to handle with it. It's working but not the way I want, my code I'm using only take the last entry and save it to the first episode from the movie.
Here is my code.

```
for ($e = 0; $e < count($_POST["episode"]); $e++) {

    $con->query("UPDATE anime_episode SET ep_title = '".$_POST['episode']."' WHERE ep_nr = $e AND ani_id = $a");
}
```

Comment: So how/where does `$a` come into the picture? Or did you mean `$e`?

Comment: ep_nr and $a are sete earlier in the code, that's no problem at all.

Comment: Is your POST (input) variable setup as an array? I.e.: `name="episode[]`

Comment: The values of the episode fields are not set in any other part of the code. This coude you can see here is the only thing I do to catch the values of the episode fields...
EDIT: ep_nr are given with $e sorry for that little mistake.

Comment: Ok sorry, made an error. I mistook the `for` for a `foreach`

Comment: if `$_POST["episode"]` is array (you take count of it) then how does it used in `update set ep_title = array`? Maybe it should be `$_POST["episode"][$e]`?

Comment: What if you were to add `LIMIT 1` at the end of your query? I.e.: `AND ani_id = $a LIMIT 1` then again I might be wrong, am having trouble understanding your question. Is it modifying ALL entries, or just the one?

Answer (score 0):

There can only be one $_POST["episode"]. PHP will group all of the entries into that one variable so count will always return 1. You should try parsing $_POST["episode"] into an array or something first and then counting those elements.

Comment: I already realized that and now I'm trying to do this.. With no result. Any idea how I can do this? I'm pretty new in php

Comment: Try using parse_str and looping through the array
$array = array();
parse_str($_POST['episode'], $array);